# How would this be done in JavaScript. Using a variable in a concatenate string

Tags: javascript

Ok. The code here is in fact Javascript but I can not find a way to fixing the problem in javascript. The code below is javascript.

```
var =inputdata; 
dataout = data.items.inputdata.time
```

This is how it would sort of look like if it was php

```
dataout = data.items.$inputdata.time
```

I would like inputdata to be treated as a variable and not as text.
Sorry for the small amount detail

Comment: `var =inputdata;` is invalid syntax.

Comment: I know its = something else above

Comment: *"This is how it would sort of look like if it was php"* In PHP, `.` is the concatenation operator. `data` and `items` would be constants. Do you really want to concatenate the value of `data` with the value of `items`? E.g. if `data = 'foo'` and `items = 'bar'` do you want the result to be `'foobar'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use square bracket notation:

```
dataout = data.items[inputdata].time
```

This will allow you to use a string in place of a key for a javascript object.